# Passing parameters to fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I'm just learning Pythos fixtures in Pytest. So far I couldn't find an example of how to pass function's parameters in a fixture. Something like this:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('checkname')
class TestFixtures:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('name', ['Gloria', 'Haley'])
    def test_one(self):
        print("Test one executed")
```

And in conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def checkname():
    print(name) #Undefined!
```

Should I make the 'name' parameter visible in a class, or is it possible to pass the parameter to the fixture somehow? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're trying to do here. You want the fixture to be able to see the values passed in as parameters in each test?

Comment: Yes exactly. Just wonder if that's possible or if better alternatives exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass parameters to fixture you can use indirect parametrization:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def checkname(request):
    print(request.param)

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('checkname')
class TestFixtures:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('checkname', ['Gloria', 'Haley'], indirect=True)
    def test_one(self):
        print("Test one executed")
```